# Linux run command from file in batches

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I got a file which contains thousands of curl post commands. I need to run them in batches of 100.

Input file contains all the commands.

```
curl -v -XPOST -H "Content-type:application/json" -d '{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint
curl -v -XPOST -H "Content-type:application/json" -d '{"k3":"v3","k4":"v4"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint
curl -v -XPOST -H "Content-type:application/json" -d '{"k5":"v5","k6":"v6"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint
```

I tried below command, even with -n1 argument its not considering whole line as an argument instead splitting it on spaces or talking whole file as input instead of single line.

```
xargs -n1 -P100 -p bash -c  < inputFile
Output
bash -c curl?...
bash -c -v?...
bash -c -XPOST?...
bash -c -H?...
bash -c Content-type:application/json?...

xargs -n1 -0 -P100 -p bash -c  < inputFile
Output
bash -c curl -v -XPOST -H "Content-type:application/json" -d '{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint
curl -v -XPOST -H "Content-type:application/json" -d '{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint?...
```

How can i run it for each line of input file?

Comment: You mean something like [gnu parallel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel)?

Answer (score 2):

## GNU `xargs`

```sh
xargs -d '\n' -n1 -P100 sh -c < input.txt
```

## Other `xargs`

```sh
tr '\n' '\0' < input.txt | xargs -0 -P100 -n1 sh -c
```

## How to debug `xargs`?

I would suggest use your favorite programming language to debug. Mine is Ruby, for example:

```sh
ruby -e 'p ARGV'
```

or NodeJS:

```sh
node -e 'console.log(process.argv)'
```

Put the above commands between `xargs` and the command you want to execute, for example:

```sh
xargs -n1 -P100 ruby -e 'p ARGV' bash -c < input.txt
```

```
["bash", "-c", "-v"]
["bash", "-c", "curl"]
["bash", "-c", "-XPOST"]
["bash", "-c", "-H"]
["bash", "-c", "https://httpbin.org/post"]
["bash", "-c", "-v"]
["bash", "-c", "-d"]
["bash", "-c", "Content-type:application/json"]
["bash", "-c", "curl"]
["bash", "-c", "{\"k1\":\"v1\",\"k2\":\"v2\"}"]
["bash", "-c", "{\"k3\":\"v3\",\"k4\":\"v4\"}"]
["bash", "-c", "-H"]
["bash", "-c", "Content-type:application/json"]
["bash", "-c", "-XPOST"]
["bash", "-c", "-d"]
["bash", "-c", "https://httpbin.org/post"]
["bash", "-c", "curl"]
["bash", "-c", "-v"]
["bash", "-c", "-XPOST"]
["bash", "-c", "-H"]
["bash", "-c", "Content-type:application/json"]
["bash", "-c", "-d"]
["bash", "-c", "{\"k5\":\"v5\",\"k6\":\"v6\"}"]
["bash", "-c", "https://httpbin.org/post"]z
```

```sh
xargs -d '\n' -n1 -P100 ruby -e 'pp ARGV' sh -c < input.txt
```

```
["sh",
 "-c",
 "curl -v -XPOST -H \"Content-type:application/json\" -d '{\"k1\":\"v1\",\"k2\":\"v2\"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint"]
["sh",
 "-c",
 "curl -v -XPOST -H \"Content-type:application/json\" -d '{\"k3\":\"v3\",\"k4\":\"v4\"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint"]
["sh",
 "-c",
 "curl -v -XPOST -H \"Content-type:application/json\" -d '{\"k5\":\"v5\",\"k6\":\"v6\"}' http://localhost:8080/v1/SomeEndPoint"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If each line is a fully constructed command, `xargs` is the wrong tool.

Both of these will work:

`sed -n 1,100p inputFile | while read line; do eval "$line"; done`

`sed -n 1,100p inputFile | while read line; do echo "$line" | sh; done`

Comment: He needs to run them in batches of 100. Your command only executes a single line at a time.

Comment: Oops, I missed that part. Fixed.

Comment: I understood the question as if he wants to execute the batches in parallel, i.e., 1-100 simultaneously, then 101-200 simultaneously and so on.

Comment: @Green绿色 I think you may be right. Since executing batch commands in parallel is not something I'm familiar with, I'm afraid I can't offer any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the most elegant solution, but it could work:

```
input_file=test.sh
batch_size=100
nlines=$(wc -l $input_file | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
for i in $(seq 1 $batch_size $nlines); do
    for j in $(seq $i $((i+batch_size))); do
        line="$(sed -n ${j}p $input_file)"
        eval "$line" &
    done
    wait
done
```

It takes batches of n lines and executes them individually in the background with `eval`. After each batch, it waits for each background process to terminate (`wait`).